# Creating a DataTable Inside an IValueConverter Class For DataGrid Binding

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable

I need to create a DataGrid that is bound to an object that is similar to the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the headers needed for the table aren't the property names of the object so I can't just use AutoGenerateColumns off the bat. My idea so far is to use a converter to take the MyClass objects and convert them into a DataTable.

```
public object Convert(
    object value, 
    Type targetType, 
    object parameter, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var items = value as IEnumerable<MyClass>;
    if (items != null)
    {
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (MyClass item in items)
            dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(item.Header, typeof(string)));

        return dTable;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

I'm setting the containing grid's DataContext to be a `List<MyClass>` object and the Convert() method is hit and the DataTable is created OK by the looks of things, but when I come to run the app, the DataGrid is just blank. Here's a basic view of my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:DataTableConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any ideas why the DataGrid remains empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's blank, you're creating a `DataTable` without any rows.

If I understand your (slightly odd) design correctly, each `MyClass` represents one column with all its values. To display that, you have to fill the rows of the `DataTable` with values from your class:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var items = value as IEnumerable<MyClass>;
    if (items != null)
    {
        var array = items.ToArray();
        var dTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (MyClass item in array)
            dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(item.Header, typeof(string)));

        if (array.Length > 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < array[0].Values.Length; i++)
                dTable.Rows.Add(array.Select(mc => mc.Values[i]).ToArray());

        return dTable;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What would be a better approach to the design then?

Comment: @Tom, I have no idea why you are doing this, so it is possible that this is the best option. But generally speaking, you should have a collection of objects of some concrete type, where each object represents one row.

Comment: The problem I have is that the object represents potentially n columns - could be 1, could be 100 - each having only one or zero values (essentially a label w/textbox affair). The solution doesn't feel right... but it is a solution for now :)